# hiding table cells with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if someone could help me hide table cells based on certain criteria. I would like to interogate every element inside the table cell (td) tag and hide the parent node (td) only if every element that is nested does not have a style of "display:none;" I'm currently using javascript to do this, but it hides (td) that have one occurence of "display:none;" So as long every element within the  does not have "style:display:none;" leave it alone, otherwise hide it. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVeXN.png]

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var links = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i=0; i<links.length; i++)
    {
        if(links[i].outerHTML.indexOf("BaseType") != -1 && 
          links[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className == "level-section")
        {
           links[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
           links[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        }
   }
   </script>
```

Comment: You've added jQuery as a tag, do you want a jQuery solution or a pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `display: none` for a `td`? Doing so messes up your table.

Comment: It will mess up your table if you hide tables. Mess = Bad

Comment: If you `hide` a `td`, aren't you concerned with the format of the table? Are you prepared to expand other columns to take it's place? Or do you just want to hide the *contents* of the table cell?

Comment: @Teemu: Good question, hidding `tr` is fine but `td`?

Comment: Use divs instead. You can simulate a table with the `display: table-cell` and `display:table`

Comment: What Teemu said. And also, why are you trying to hide an element *and its parent*? Hiding the parent alone will hide the children too.

Comment: Maybe give us some code of that table, from this script we see nothing and totally don't understand what You want to do and what for.

Comment: `id`s must be unique within a document, yours are not. Maybe you need a `class`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to use jQuery or not. And since there's already a couple jQuery answers already here's a pure JavaScript solution:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Rxv/1/)

#### Javascript

```
var data = document.querySelectorAll('td');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(data, function(td){

    var hide = Array.prototype.some.call(td.children, function(div){
        return div.style.display == "none";
    });

    if (hide) {
        td.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$('#tableId').find('td').each(function(){
    var noHide = 0; 
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
            noHide++;       
        }
    })

    if (noHide != 0) {
        $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
    }

})
```

Actually set visibility to hidden in cells it's better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('#column'),function(){
   if($('div:visible',this).length == 0)
      $(this).hide();
   else
      $(this).show();
});
```

This will work, but Your code is incorrect. Id of elements should be unique, use class instead: `<td class="column" />` and `$('.column')` instead of `$('#column')` in above code.

Comment: Not related, but there's a funny feature in jQuery, it returns fluently also doubled `id`s.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work in IE for example. At least in older versions. I remember I had problems with that.